# Qt - Spinbox look on linux (gnome)

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have made up a layout for my Qt app in qt-designer.
In layout editor it looks like this:
[image]

In the running app on linux (fedora 23 with gnome) it looks like this:
[image]

So the plus/minus button are so big that they cover whole area of the spinbox. Which is not that I expect. I checked other apps and for example in mtPaint I have normal looking spinboxes, and I want them like this:
[image]

What can I do to make it look the same as on the last image?

Comment: Are you having the same behaviour when creating the QSpinBox programmatically (not using Qt Designer)?

Comment: @jpo38 I could try it sometime, but I want to use designer anyway to create and edit the layout.

Comment: Just try it to see if the problem comes from Qt Designer or from QWidget library config.

Comment: @jpo38 Can't do it right now, but I see that my other app created on windows has the same issue, when I run it in Fedora. So probably it is some run-time issue.

Comment: Have you tried forcing it from `PlusMinus` to `UpDownArrows` using `setButtonSymbols`?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall adwaita-qt4 on Fedora 23.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11242639)

Comment: I have the same issue and uninstalling adwaita-qt4 solves spinbox look on Fedora 23. What is wrong with my answer ?